How does the app registered in Azure AD support multi tenants to request access token for SharePoint Online?
I recently registered app in Azure AD for SharePoint Online access with OAuth authentication. The account type was set to Multitenant, and the API permissions are set as followings:
account type
API permissions
Everything is working fine with the accounts under the organization where the app was registered.
Now I have a customer under another organization in Azure AD who wants to request the token with the same application ID to access their SharePoint API, but we got the error as below:
token request error
I was wondering why the token request requires admin consent for the other tenant? The application is already set to support Multitenant. Please give me some suggestions of how to resolve the problem. Thank you in advanced.

To resolve the problem, the tenant admin of the other organization needs to grant admin consent to the application.
